# B2 visa and married to US Citizen - barred from US, what next?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

I was traveling on B2; immigration won’t let me go to the USA because I overstayed November 2014-March 2015.They said I will need a visa to go back to the USA. I married to a citizen a year ago and we haven’t file the paperwork which as yet. I was scared to tell the truth that I am married because we haven’t filed the paperwork.

1. My question is what do I need to do to get back to the USA? I want to go back and then start the paperwork.
2. How will I know if I am denial?
3. there anything I need to do to get back to the state and file the paperwork?

Comment: You wish to go back to the US to visit or to immigrate?

Comment: Why does the title say "barred from US"? It doesn't seem like you are barred from the US.

Comment: Is it possible that you are from Barbados, and have a baby born in Barbados? Did you ask about this on the Travel site? Did you travel to the US while you were married?

Answer (score 4):

Well, firstly you ALWAYS need to tell the truth.  If at any point you're caught lying by immigration, it might be considered fraud, and then you'll never get back in.

They've already told you - to get back to the US, you'll need a visa. So you'll need to do that first.

If the visa fails, there's usually a rejection reason telling you if you're denied.

Finally, yes, get yourself an immigration lawyer. It might not be cheap, but they'll be far more likely to know little tips or changes you can do to your application to help you with the process. You don't want to make any more mistakes at this point - so get professional help with the application.  The internet is great, but it is unlikely to be a suitable substitute for an immigration professional in this case.